# Keep non submitted values, when pressing "more-Button"

Tags: jsf

First, my scenario:

I have a form including several input fields. Some of them are hidden by default, because they are not really often needed:

```
<h:form>
    <!-- with validators -->
    <h:inputText>...</h:inputText>
    <h:inputText>...</h:inputText>

    <!-- show this fields only when the user wants to -->
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!bean.hide}">
        <h:inputText>...</h:inputText>
        <h:inputText>...</h:inputText>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:commandButton value="Show / hide more fields" actionListener="#{bean.toogleHide}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

This would be the bean:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Bean {
    // with getter
    private boolean hide = true;

    public void toogleHide(ActionEvent event) {
        hide = !hide;
    }
}
```

What i want to do:

Assume, a user fills the first to input fields with valid / invalid data. Now he wants to see the other inputfields that are hidden by default. So would press the command button "show / hide more fields".

=> is there a way the keep the non submitted values when pressing the "show / hide more fields" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to always send the "hidden fields" from your JSF page, but make them `display: none` by default, using CSS. Then hide/unhide them with javascript only, e.g. jQuery or a small JS script on the page. The whole will be much more responsive, plus you don't have the issue you're fighting with.

Comment: I really like this approach! :-)